# Create Function Type (TypeScript Interface)

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I need to make a function type that tells me what the type must be for the second value based on the first value

```js
  type BType = number | string | array
  enum AEnum = { number = "number" , string : "string" , array : "array"} 

  const fc = (a : AEnum , b : BType)=>{ 
   //...
  }
```

What I need is that when `a = AEnum.array`, then `b` must be `array`, or an error should be shown

How can I make something like this ??

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz I think the question is actually quite clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just overload the function !

```
type BType = number | string | []
enum AEnum { number = "number", string = "string", array = "array" }

function foo(a: AEnum.number, b: number): unknown;
function foo(a: AEnum.string, b: string): unknown;
function foo(a: AEnum.array, b: []): unknown;
function foo(a: AEnum, b: BType): unknown {
    return void;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgKuaBeKA7ArgWwEYQE5QA%20UAzsHgJaoDmRUA2gLoBQEGmUAggKLtQDeaLLgIoAROxFiANKXJVa4spRoyoAQzx51IKOM3aQYqAF9mzAGbpUAY2AUA9qigWHDgBTqAXF15YAdJL4stg%20QXgAlD7WANaoDgDuqADcltZ2js6uHt6%207P7KCiE%20hTRRULHxSalWtvZOLm6ePjz5BjrFDIzllYkpaXWZjTktfpid8Ig9qHF9AsxQi1B4EMDoeM4Abg4UACapZkA)